# Why does autoload/myplugin.vim get sourced?

Tags: plugin-system, autoload

I noticed that when functions in `plugin/myplugin.vim` are named using the autoload convention, `function! myplugin#myfunction()`, the file `autoload/myplugin.vim` gets sourced on `vim` startup, even though no function of that file is ever called during the startup process. This happens for example with [vim-peekaboo](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-peekaboo/blob/master/plugin/peekaboo.vim). Changing the functions `peekaboo#{on,off}` to e.g. `Peekaboo_{on,off}` fixes the issue, but I was wondering whether this was documented behavior? Also, is there a canonical way of naming functions in `plugin/myplugin.vim`?

Comment: Yes this is documented; this is how autoloaded functions work. Any function with that type of name causes autoload files to be searched and possibly sourced. I dont tend to put many functions in plugin.

Comment: Thanks, but wouldn't you expect vim to check first whether the function is already defined?

Comment: Read the section on autoloading-functions

Comment: It says the following (emphasis mine): When such a function is called, **and it is not defined yet**, Vim will search the "autoload" directories in 
 runtimepath' for a script file called "filename.vim". Or am I missing something?

Comment: Perhaps the function definition causes vim to check if such a function is defined? Particularly if using `function!`

Comment: Ah, that might be the explanation, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but my theory is that during startup the definition of a function (particularly using `function!`) causes vim to check if a function by that name is defined, and this in turn causes the autoload search.

Feedback from contributors to vim would be welcome, in order to decide whether this is a bug or a feature.